# Want to iterate a function 10 times , and take average of its value (python)

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a function with 4 arguments, i want to iterate this function 10 times, and have that counter as an argument for the function too. here's the function I want to iterate:

```
np.random.seed(1)  
def  propagate ( seed ,  network ,  threshold ,  steps ): 
      "" "Start cascade from node` seed` of network `net`." "" 
      activated  =  [ seed ] 
      pocket  =  [ seed ] 
      exposition  =  {} 
      time  =  0 
      while  time  <  steps : 
          time  +=  1 
          # propagate 
          for  seed  in  pocket : 
              for  out_node  in  network . successors( seed ): 
                  add_weight  =  network [ seed ] [ out_node ] [ "weight" ] 
                  if  out_node  not  in  activated : 
                      if  out_node  in  exposition : 
                          exposition [ out_node ]  +=  add_weight 
                      else : 
                          exposition [ out_node ]  =  add_weight 
          # activate 
          pocket  =  [] 
          for  node ,  total  in  exposition .items (): 
              if  total  =  threshold : 
                  pocket . append ( node ) 
         activated  +=  pocket [:] 
         for  node  in  pocket : 
             del  exposition [ node ] 
     return  len ( activated )z
```

I want to choose 10 nodes , network is a graph stored,iterate(argument is steps) it 5 times, have threshold have values from 1-5 , and calculate the average nos of activated nodes. here's what I have tried. its not much but I am not understanding how it should work either.

```
act_nodes=[]  
for i in range(1,5):
    propagate(1,B,5,i)
    act_nodes.append(propagate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the result of your function:

```
 act_nodes=[] 
 for i in range(1,5):
     x=propagate(1,B,5,i)
     act_nodes.append(x)
```

"activated" is declared inside the function and is not living outside it, that is the error for.
Also, why are you looping in range(1,5)? This will run 4 times but you said that you need 10?

Comment: Oh damn! could you tell me what happened with you did x=? it stored the output in x and added to the list?

Comment: @Chai Yes, Exactly